# How can I find the eigenvalues of this 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a test in Algebra in a few days and a problem with eigenvalues will be there. I tried many ways to solve it and none helped me. How could you find the eigenvalues of the following matrix?

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}8 &-6 &2\\-6 &7 &-4\\2 &-4 &3\end{pmatrix}$$

I've tried add/substract rows and columns and the way this pdf shows https://www.scss.tcd.ie/~dahyotr/CS1BA1/SolutionEigen.pdf

Comment: The way to calculate the eigenvalues in such cases is pretty straightforward. What have you tried?

Comment: Do you know about characteristic polynomials?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: One shortcut here: since this matrix is symmetric, there is an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors, so once you’ve found eigenvectors for two distinct eigenvalues, you can compute a third with a cross product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have some (course) notes on the topic? You find the eigenvalues by solving:
$$\det\left(A-\lambda I_n\right)=0$$
where $A$ is the $n\times n$-matrix given and $I_n$ is the identity matrix. In your case, this means solving:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
8-\lambda & -6 & 2 \\ -6& 7-\lambda & -4 \\ 2 & -4 & 3-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

> I've tried add/substract rows and columns and the way this pdf shows

Do you know how to calculate a ($3 \times 3$) determinant?

You can use properties of determinants to try and simplify the calculations, but you can also go for the straightforward calculation by expanding along a column or row of your choice: that will lead to a 3rd degree polynomial equation in $\lambda$.

Comment: A down-vote seems a bit harsh?

Comment: I concur: +1 from me.